# Android SQLite quiz crashes after two questions when it should be doing five

Tags: android, sqlite, logcat

i am creating a quiz app and it crashes after doing two questions when the app should be going through 5 questions. i'm not sure why as i followed a tutorial to get the basics down. here is the QuizActivity

```
public class QuizActivity extends Activity
{
List<Question> quesList;
int score=0;
int qid=0;
Question currentQ;
TextView txtQuestion;
RadioButton rda, rdb, rdc;
Button butNext;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
    DBHelper db=new DBHelper(this);
    quesList=db.getAllQuestions();
    currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
    txtQuestion=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    rda=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
    rdb=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    rdc=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);
    butNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    setQuestionView();
    butNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            RadioGroup grp=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
            RadioButton answer=(RadioButton)findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            if(currentQ.getANSWER().equals(answer.getText()))
            {
                score++;
            }
                currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
                setQuestionView();
                if(qid<5)
                {
                    currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
                    setQuestionView();
                }
                else
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putInt("score", score); //Your score
                    intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
        }

        });
}
private void setQuestionView()
{
    txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());
    rda.setText(currentQ.getOPTA());
    rdb.setText(currentQ.getOPTB());
    rdc.setText(currentQ.getOPTC());
    qid++;
}

}
```

it pushes through to the ResultsActivity

```
public class ResultActivity extends Activity
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
    //get rating bar object
    RatingBar bar=(RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
    //get text view
    TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textResult);
    //get score
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    int score= b.getInt("score");
    //display score
    bar.setRating(score);
    switch (score)
    {
    case 1:
    case 2: t.setText("Oopsie! Better Luck Next Time!");
    break;
    case 3:
    case 4:t.setText("Hmmmm.. Someone's been reading a lot of trivia");
    break;
    case 5:t.setText("Who are you? A trivia wizard???");
    break;
    }
}
}
```

and here is the logcat errors

> 05-15 10:50:04.686: W/dalvikvm(12197): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41f758b0)
>   05-15 10:50:04.696: E/AndroidRuntime(12197): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   05-15 10:50:04.696: E/AndroidRuntime(12197): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 4, size is 4
>   05-15 10:50:04.696: E/AndroidRuntime(12197):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
>   05-15 10:50:04.696: E/AndroidRuntime(12197):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
>   05-15 10:50:04.696: E/AndroidRuntime(12197):    at com.example.timestableseasy.QuizActivity$1.onClick(QuizActivity.java:50)
>   05-15 10:50:04.696: E/AndroidRuntime(12197):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4421)
>   05-15 10:50:04.696: E/AndroidRuntime(12197):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17903)
>   05-15 10:50:04.696: E/AndroidRuntime(12197):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
>   05-15 10:50:04.696: E/AndroidRuntime(12197):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   05-15 10:50:04.696: E/AndroidRuntime(12197):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
>   05-15 10:50:04.696: E/AndroidRuntime(12197):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
>   05-15 10:50:04.696: E/AndroidRuntime(12197):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   05-15 10:50:04.696: E/AndroidRuntime(12197):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>   05-15 10:50:04.696: E/AndroidRuntime(12197):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
>   05-15 10:50:04.696: E/AndroidRuntime(12197):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
>   05-15 10:50:04.696: E/AndroidRuntime(12197):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `setQuestionView();` twice on your `Button` click as a result of which `qid` is increased by 2 each time you click the `Button` instead of 1

Comment: is that why it crashes of is that a separate issue?

Comment: Yeah that's the reason it is crashing you should only call that function once because it is incrementing your `qid` or change the place where you increment your `qid`

Answer (score 1):

Indices start from 0, so a `List` with 4 elements will have indices from 0 to 3. Accessing index 4 is out of bounds:

```
currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
```

you need to make sure `qid` is `< 4`, or more generally, `< quesList.size()`.

Why you hit the limit after two questions is because you're incrementing `qid` twice for each question.